# JavaScript: How to create and save text file

Tags: javascript, file

I need to create a new .txt file with answers written in it. I'm using Javascript.
How to do it? I think hard coding will be the best because I'm not allowed to use jQuery , filesaver plugins and etc...

Everything works in browser with .html file. Also it's not duplicate... I need to create file locally to .html file directory, without any url's and other stuff.. This code will work in browser locally, not online.
Thanks!

Comment: I think it would be helpful to specify the environment: browser, or nodejs? (Although, from the mention of jQuery, I suspect it is browser...)

Comment: Yes, it's browser..